# How would I construct an object array so that I could reference properties in this way?

Tags: javascript

My app has multiple screens and I want to store properties for each screen in an object. I want to be able to reference it easily by name, for instance:

```
var homelabel = screen('home').label;
```

or

```
var settingsIcon = screen['settings'].icon;
```

How would this be done?

Comment: you could make `screen` an object then access it like `screen['home']` or `screen['settings']`, unless you're talking about different html pages, that's a different problem

Comment: `screen` would need to be a function that *returns* an object for that. And no, there are no arrays involved.

Comment: What about `screen.home.label` or `screen.settings.icon` -  that's out of the box behavior for a normal object.  If you need parentheses, screen will have to be a function.

Comment: I would prefer a string because my HTML elements will have something like `data-target='home'` and it would be easy to calll `screen[$(this).data('target')].label`

Comment: You can also do that with a regular old object. eg `screen['home'].label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let screen = {
  "home": {
    "icon": "home_icon.png",
    "label": "home_label"
  },
  "settings": {
    "icon": "settings_icon.png",
    "label": "settings_label"
  }
}

console.log(screen["home"].label);
console.log(screen["settings"].icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

`screen` must be a function that returns an object with whatever passed to the function. You can move `screens` variable out of the function, and then you can access it directly through reference.

```js
 var screens = {
     home: { 
         label: 'Home', 
         icon: 'fa fa-home' 
     },
     settings: { 
         label: 'Settings',
         icon: 'fa fa-cog'
     }
 };
   
function screen(screenType){
   
   if(screenType in screens){
      return screens[screenType];
   }
    
   return {};

}

var home = screen('home').label;

console.log(home);

console.log( screens['home'].icon );
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it just in your question, create a function and return an object. If the property you call the function with doesn't exist, you should return an empty object to avoid errors.

```js
function screen(prop) {
  let obj = {
    home: {
      label: 'foo'
    },
    settings: {
      icon: 'bar'
    }
  };

  return obj[prop] || {};
}


console.log(screen('home').label); //foo
console.log(screen('foo').bar); //undefined
```